# Hover event stopping a mouse enter event the first time its called.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I have a list of items that a user can add to via javascript. What I want is when a user mouses over the list-item make the glyphicon visible. Right now it will work but only after the user mouses in then mouses out of the list-item. After they do that once they mouse back over the list-item will it begin to work.

Jquery:

```
//When the user hovers over a list item give them the option to delete it
$('.list-item-container').hover(function(){
    $('.list-item').on({
        mouseover: function(){
            $('.glyphicon-remove', this).css('visibility', 'visible');

            //When the user click to remove the list item remove it from the list
            $('.glyphicon-remove').on('click', function(){
                //TODO: Popup modal for delete confirmation
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        },
        mouseout: function(){
            $('.glyphicon-remove', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="list-item-wrapper">
    <ul class="list-item-container">
        <li class="row list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="item-done">
            <label for="list-done">My to-do-list</label>

            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: question is unclear! please explain a little bit more!

Comment: You should do this with CSS - much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code attaches the event on mouseover (every time too - not great) - so you're code isn't doing what you intend it to do.

This is much easier with CSS.

```
.glyphicon-remove {
    visibility: hidden;
}


.list-item-container:hover .glyphicon-remove {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Then, the only JavaScript required is to remove the element.

```
$('.list-item-container').on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```